# $\ell^p$-spaces for $p<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

It is well known that whenever $p\in (0,1)$, the mapping
$$
d_p(x,y):=\|x-y\|_{\ell^p}:=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n-y_n|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}
$$
turns 
$$\ell^p:=\{(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}:\|x\|_{\ell^p}<\infty\}$$
into a complete metric space.

Are there interesting applications of these spaces? I'm aware of the somewhat related Hamming distance, but I am wondering whether something more substantially mathematical exists.